# Python DHCP enabled disabled check

Tags: python, python-3.8, dhcp

I'm using Python 3.8.5 currently on windows, but the script should run also on linux and on macOS.

I'm creating UDP server and a client and have establish communication between them via multicast.
The client does not know from advanced the IP of the server so it is a "discovery tool" that will let me know information about the server ones it has received the data. -This is working-

On the server I'm using netifaces to get information about the interfaces.

The server sends information to the client such as IP address, mask, gateway. -information that I get from netifaces and is working-.
Example of data I get:

[image]
[image]

**Now to the issue:**
The python server can have a static IP or can be connected to a DHCP server -in case that is connected to a DHCP server I will not have access to the DHCP server-.

I wish to know when the DHCP is enabled or disable on the python server so I can send this as a flag to the client together with the rest of the information.

The idea is for the client to know that the IP that he's connecting to can change and he may lose connection and will need to start the discovery tool once more.

Because the user will not know in advanced if the python server is connected to a DHCP server or wil know the IP address of the python server or have access to the python server command line or configuration, using ip addr show, ipconfig, ifconfig and other commands before connecting is not an option.

I have seen that people use scrapy for DHCP communications but it seems that it does not solves what I wish to accomplish.
I do no need to configure the DHCP, just detect if my python server IP is static or dynamic.

I have search for over 4 days and have not found a possible solution.
I'm not asking to have the solution in silver spoon just to be pointed on the right direction.

**EDIT: I forgot to mention that the python server will be running on Ubuntu 16.04 and 20.04.

Comment: Why not just use DNS and hostnames?

Comment: Jared Smith, thank you for your comment. Sadly that is not an option. At least at the moment

Comment: Why not? You might want to give more detail about what you are actually trying to accomplish with your server/client application, this is starting to smell like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676).

Comment: Jared Smith,For security reasons the devices will not be connected to the internet only to a LAN.
There are many configurations, for example only one python server on the system no DHCP server.
the user will need to connect to it while on site with out knowing the IP. 
The python client connects to the server via multicast and gets the information shown on the pictures. Then the user can change his computer config to be able to connect to the sever. Second configuration, the LAN as a DHCP server and our python server is connected to it, the python client works the same as before.

Comment: I have already establish connection to the server. This is not the issue. I wish to know as extra information if the IP I'm connected at the moment is a dynamic or static IP in case I lose communication or if in the future I need to connect to this server again.
If I have static IP I can save the IP in a data base and skip the discovery step.

Comment: None of that explains why you can't use DNS instead of raw IP addresses. Nor does it explain why the answer posted doesn't work, because it totally answers the question you posted. So what's your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your operating system setup. For example, here's a related question on [how to detect whether DHCP is enabled in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44376/30497).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Florian,
As mention, the user will not have access to the CLI, terminal, GUI or IP of the python server. 
That is why using commands like the ones in the question you pointed to helps me i this case.

Comment: If you have Python running on the server (that's how I understand your question) then you can either open the files mentioned in the answer I linked via normal Python tools (e.g. `open`) or run a command via the `subprocess` module.